# How can I round up to integer devided number?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try this method `Math.round` to round up the devided numer:

```
Math.round(10/3)
```

But the result is 3.

```js
function ddd() {
  alert(Math.round(10 / 3));
}
```

```html
<button onclick="ddd()">click</button>
```

How can I round up to integer devided number?

Comment: What result are you trying to get?

Comment: Use Math.ceil()

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use 'ceil' which will give you 4, if thats what you wanted?

```
Math.ceil(10/3)
```

'round' gives you the nearest whole number (.5 rounds up).

```
Math.round()
```

'floor' gives the next lowest whole number (will always round down).

```
Math.floor()
```

And finally 'ceil' will give you next highest whole number (will always round up).

```
Math.ceil()
```

Comment: add `parseInt()`, `toFixed()` also, Give him all the option to choose ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```js
let roundPrecision = 3;

let val = 10/3;

console.log(Math.round(val*Math.pow(10, roundPrecision))/Math.pow(10, roundPrecision));
```